# how to send TCP Requests in java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am using Sockets to connect using TCP and I want to make different calls. e.g. Get InputValue
I have these type of different requests which I want to make from already running server.

```
Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
             System.out.println("Just connected to " 
             + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
             OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
             DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
             String func="Get inputvalue";
             byte[] tRequest = encoder.string2bytes(func);
             out.write(tRequest);
             out.flush();

             System.out.println("write done");
             InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
             DataInputStream in =
                            new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
             System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
```

It says it connected as just connected printout got printed. Write done print is also printed but no data is returned and the program keeps on running.
If I use telnet then this same request call returns data successfully.

So the question is how to make TCP calls in java?

**Update:**  I solved this by:

```
PrintWriter toServer = 
                    new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                BufferedReader fromServer = 
                    new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                toServer.println("Get inputvalue\r\n"); 
                String line = "";
                System.out.println("Client received: ");
                while ((line = fromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
```

but the program keeps on running in the while loop and prints nothing. how to check that response is ended?

Comment: Wild guess: change that to `String func="Get inputvalue\n";`. Perhaps the server waits for a newline before sending a response.

Comment: sorry, its not working

Comment: What server are you connecting to?

Comment: already developed server which uses TCP for services. I don't have any other knowledge of it. I just know the calls to make

Comment: may be `String func="Get inputvalue\r\n"`

Comment: yes I tried this too, but not solving my problem

Comment: You are reading too late. Do it on a separate thread. And start reading before you send.

Comment: At least open the inputstream before you send request.

Comment: I have moved 
 InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
             DataInputStream in =
                            new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
these two lines before out.write. still the same problem. its not moving after these two lines.

Comment: As Fildor said, you need to do reading in a separate thread. You can't reliably do it all in one thread. Threading in Java is easy, just do it.

Comment: You can't use `readUTF()` unless the peer is using `writeUTF()`, and *vice versa.*

Comment: I have solved it without threading and without readUTF. please read the update in the question